# How to send multiple data from one fragment to another simultaneously by clicking a button?

Tags: java, android

My problem is how to update all fragment simultaneously when getting the result of string from other fragment. There are 3 fragment name MainFragment , Menu4 , Menu5.

For example, I have 2 variable string array in MainFragment. String array A and String array B. Because I am using a fragment , I will use bundle which will transfer the string to Menu4 and it WORKS.

This is the code for the bundle in MainFragment.When button click ,it will send to other fragment.

```
 FragmentTransaction transection = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                Menu4 mfragment=new Menu4();
                //using Bundle to send data
                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("email", populateRpmData1[0]);
                mfragment.setArguments(bundle);
                transection.replace(R.id.content_frame, mfragment);
                transection.commit();
```

As you can see , populateRpmData1[0] is my String array A which will transfer to Fragment Menu4.But how can I do when button click, String array B also will transfer simultenously to other fragment called Menu5 ?

Comment: you put your code in onclicklistener for button.

Comment: @KaranMer  i already put .But that is not the answer.

Comment: then what is happening? is it not showing second fragment on click or data is not passing. post additional code on how you are getting this data in second fragmetn.